# How do I italicize a queried word in a string React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a user query search input to italicized matching text in a string

for example, if I search 'hap' the results would show the entire word "happy" and "happening" italicized in a larger string

the string would be shown as 'i am so *happy* today because so much is *happening*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: have you tried string replace?

Comment: find out this solutions:  https://dev.to/comscience/highlight-searched-text-on-a-page-with-just-javascript-17b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text that needs to be italicized is short enough (e.g. one sentence) you could render each word as separate `<span>` element and italicize the elements that contain the user query search input.

e.g.

```js
import React from "react";

function Word({ word, isItalic }) {
  return <span>{isItalic ? <i>{word}</i> : word}</span>;
}

function Italicizer({ text, textToFind }) {
  const words = text.split(" ");
  const wordComponents = words.map((word) => (
    <Word word={word} isItalic={word.includes(textToFind)} />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      {wordComponents.map((component) => (
        <>{component} </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Italicizer;
```

You could then use this component like so:

```
<Italicizer text="Hey I'm so happy" textToFind="happy" />
```

Please bear in mind a few things with the above:

1. It won't handle paragraphs or new lines, you'll need to handle those by rendering `<p>` or `<div>` elements based on finding `\n` or `\r` characters
2. If there's a lot of words it's going to get pretty slow as the component execute `.includes` on every single word. You should be able to make this more performant using something like `.indexOf` on the whole text and maintaining a list of words that contain the text to find in it.
3. It's not going to handle text with multiple consecutive spaces in it, e.g. `"This text has a big   gap"`
4. The search is case sensitive. To make it case insensitive you would change `isItalic={word.toUpperCase().includes(textToFind.toUpperCase())}`

Comment: ah thank you so much!!! this works so great - I instead added a class to italicize on the span if true, instead of using a <i> tag - really appreciate it!